# Matrix equation solving

Tags: matrix-calculus

My question is very simple, but I it seems to be impossible for me to figure it out.  Here we go, find $\mathbf Z$ such that
$$
 (\mathbf Z^t\mathbf Z)^{-1}\mathbf Z^t\mathbf W=X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2
$$
Where $\mathbf Z$,  $\mathbf W$, $X_1$, $X_2$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are all matrices.

Comment: Is this related to a least squares problem?

Comment: Yes it is related but in a somewhat complicated way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that such a $Z$ exists with linearly independent columns, then $( Z^t Z)^{-1} Z^t = Z^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse of $Z$. So you could try to solve $ U W = X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2$ first by vectorization and afterwards recover $Z = (Z^+)^+ = U^+$.

Comment: Thanks a lot the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse does the trick. I am grateful